# Convert a space-delimited tree to useful dict in python

Tags: python, whitespace

I have an output (a list) of items, like such:

```
Root
  Branch1
    LeafA
    LeafB
  Branch2
    LeafC
      LeafZ
    LeafD
```

They are all two-space delimited.
I want build a logical representation of this list without the leading spaces, and retain the parent-child relationshiop.

A final possible result:

```
aDict = {
    'Root': null,
    'Branch1': 'Root',
    'LeafA': 'Branch1',
... so on and so forth
}
```

Ultimately, I want to iterate through the dictionary and retrieve the Key and parent, as well as another value from another dict based on Key.

Comment: Your possible final result isn't valid Python. Care to revise it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
tree = """Root
  Branch1
    LeafA
    LeafB
  Branch2
    LeafC
      LeafZ
    LeafD"""

aDict = {}
iDict = {}
for line in tree.split("\n"):
    key = line.lstrip(" ")
    indent = (len(line) - len(key)) / 2
    if indent == 0:
        aDict[key] = None
    else:
        aDict[key] = iDict[indent - 1]
    iDict[indent] = key

print aDict
# {'LeafD': 'Branch2', 'LeafA': 'Branch1', 'Branch2': 'Root', 'LeafC': 'Branch2', 'LeafB': 'Branch1', 'Branch1': 'Root', 'Root': None, 'LeafZ': 'LeafC'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this solves the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def f(txt):
    stack = []
    ret = {}
    for line in txt.split('\n'):
        a = line.split('  ')
        level = len(a) - 1
        key = a[-1]
        stack = stack[:level]
        ret[key] = stack[-1] if len(stack) > 0 else None
        stack.append(key)
    return ret

print f("""Root
  Branch1
    LeafA
    LeafB
  Branch2
    LeafC
      LeafZ
    LeafD""")

print f("""Root1
  Branch1
    LeafA
      LeftZ
  Branch2
    LeftB
Root2
  Branch3""")
```

Output:

```
{'LeafD': 'Branch2', 'LeafA': 'Branch1', 'Branch2': 'Root', 'LeafC': 'Branch2', 'LeafB': 'Branch1', 'Branch1': 'Root', 'Root': None, 'LeafZ': 'LeafC'}
{'LeafA': 'Branch1', 'Branch2': 'Root1', 'Branch1': 'Root1', 'LeftZ': 'LeafA', 'LeftB': 'Branch2', 'Branch3': 'Root2', 'Root1': None, 'Root2': None}
```